# Converting batch file to exe for Windows Embedded Compact (XP)

Tags: batch, batch-file, windows-embedded-2009

I’m having some trouble trying to create a very simple .exe file that starts a .url file in the same directory, when I try to run it, a pop-up message shows an error telling that:

```
“<filename.exe> is not a valid Windows Embedded Compact application”.
```

Starting from the beginning…

I first created (on my windows11 PC) a “test.bat” file with this code “start webpage.url”, inside the same directory I have already the “webpage.url”.

Then I converted the “test.bat” file into a “test.exe” file with “BatToExe Converter” with the 32bit option enabled, so now I have this folder:

```
MyFolder
    test.bat
    test.exe
    webpage.url
```

The .exe file on my win11 PC runs correctly, opening the “webpage.url” file into a web browser, but when I copy the entire folder to a Windows Embedded PC and then I try to run it, appears the pop-up error message told upon.

My question is… is there any tool capable of converting a batch file to an exe that runs on Windows Embedded Compact (XP)?

Comment: Windows Embedded Compact is Windows CE and the binaries you produce are indeed not compatible.  You didn't even mention the processor (which might very well be ARM).  Also, to be clear.. nothing "converts" a batch file into an executable.  It only provides a thin wrapper and I bet you are not going to find one that can do this.  I myself would suggest writing whatever your batch file is doing in a real language and using a compiler compatible with Embedded Compact.  Otherwise, you are probably stuck with "Pocket CMD" and leaving the file in batch form.